# How to summarize consecutive dates to a single date range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to summarize the date?

[image]

For example: I have some many date

```
A1: 1/2/2023
A2: 2/2/2023
A3: 3/2/2023
A4: 4/2/2023
A5: 6/2/2023
A6: 7/2/2023
A7: 8/2/2023
A8: 10/2/2023
A9: 12/2/2023
A10: 13/2/2023
A11: 16/2/2023
A12: 17/2/2023
A13: 20/2/2023
A14: 25/2/2023
```

How to set after VBA the result is showed below ?

```
1/2/2023-4/2/2023, 6/2/2023-8/2/2023, 10/2/2023, 12/2/2023-13/2/2023, 16/2/2023-17/2/2023, 20/2/2023, 25/2/2023
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck? We are not a free script writing service.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you help with with the Logic that you have in mind to reach the summary? Why 10/2/2023 is a single lone entry but others are a range?

Comment: @patkim (This is not an answer for OP‘s question.) 
OP seems to need to turn consecutive dates into a range, and non-consecutive dates are listed separately.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. As you can see from the comments, the question is somewhat unclear. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771474/edit) the question and add 1) the spreadsheet version you currently use 2) the formula you currently have to achieve the result and 3) the output that your formula currently produces. Please enclose all formulas & other code in code brackets `{ }`, and please don't answer in comments - if you edit your question, it'll keep up with your situation and all the relevant info is readily available.

Answer (score 1):

If ms365 is an option:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(x,A2:A14-A1:A13,REDUCE(TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy"),SEQUENCE(COUNT(x)),LAMBDA(y,z,IF(INDEX(x,z)=1,IF(LEFT(RIGHT(y,11))="-",TEXTBEFORE(y,"-",-1),y)&TEXT(INDEX(A2:A14,z),"\-dd/mm/yyyy"),y&TEXT(INDEX(A2:A14,z),"\, dd/mm/yyyy")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that writing a UDF for this problem is a little easier than inventing a long formula that will work but be difficult to understand and edit.

The function can be quite simple, something like:

```
Function getListAsString(aData As Range) As String
Dim aTemp As Variant
    aTemp = getSortedValuesFromRange(aData)
    getListAsString = getListOfDateRngsAsString(aTemp)
End Function
```

Since the source data may not be sorted, the first line of the function turns the range passed as a parameter into a sorted array.

And the second line analyzes this array of values and forms the result string.

What `getSortedValuesFromRange()` and `getListOfDateRngsAsString()` will be depends only on your preparedness for VBA programming and your ingenuity. My version of the code turned out like this:

```
Private Function getSortedValuesFromRange(aData As Range) As Variant
Dim oCell As Range
Dim aResult As Variant
Dim vDate As Double, sFormattedDate As String
    aResult = Array()
    For Each oCell In aData.Cells
        sFormattedDate = Trim(oCell.Text)
        If sFormattedDate <> vbNullString Then
            vDate = oCell.value
            Call AddOrReplace(vDate, sFormattedDate, aResult)
        End If
    Next oCell
    getSortedValuesFromRange = aResult
End Function

Private Function getListOfDateRngsAsString(aData As Variant) As String
Dim aResult As Variant, sResult As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim prevDate As Variant, sPrevDate As String
    If UBound(aData) < LBound(aData) Then Exit Function
    ReDim aResult(0 To UBound(aData), 1 To 2)
    aResult(0, 1) = LBound(aData)
    aResult(0, 2) = LBound(aData)
    j = 0
    For i = LBound(aData) + 1 To UBound(aData)
        If aData(i)(0) - aData(aResult(j, 2))(0) > 1 Then
            j = j + 1
            aResult(j, 1) = i
            aResult(j, 2) = i
        Else
            aResult(j, 2) = i
        End If
     Next i
    sResult = aData(aResult(0, 1))(1)
    If aResult(0, 1) <> aResult(0, 2) Then sResult = sResult & "-" & aData(aResult(0, 2))(1)
     For i = 1 To j
        sResult = sResult & ", "
        If aResult(i, 1) = aResult(i, 2) Then
            sResult = sResult & aData(aResult(i, 1))(1)
        Else
            sResult = sResult & aData(aResult(i, 1))(1) & "-" & aData(aResult(i, 2))(1)
        End If
     Next i
    getListOfDateRngsAsString = sResult
End Function

Private Sub AddOrReplace(key, value, aData)
Dim l&, r&, m&, N&, i&
    l = LBound(aData)
    r = UBound(aData) + 1
    N = r
    While (l < r)
        m = l + Int((r - l) / 2)
        If aData(m)(0) < key Then l = m + 1 Else r = m
    Wend
    If r = N Then
        ReDim Preserve aData(0 To N)
        aData(N) = Array(key, value)
    ElseIf aData(r)(0) = key Then
        aData(r)(1) = value
    Else
        ReDim Preserve aData(0 To N)
        For i = N - 1 To r Step -1
            aData(i + 1) = aData(i)
        Next i
        aData(r) = Array(key, value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Write in the cell `=getListAsString(A1:A30)` and get the result

```
1/2/2023-4/2/2023, 6/2/2023-8/2/2023, 10/2/2023, 12/2/2023-13/2/2023, 16/2/2023-17/2/2023, 20/2/2023, 25/2/2023
```